# Jquery vegas plugin image resize within <div> elements

Tags: jquery, image-resizing

I am using the jquery vegas plugin that re sizes the background images, yet I would like to learn how to resize the images contained within selected  elements.

Example:

- HTML `<div class="bg1"></div>`
- CSS `.bg1 {background-image: url(../img/bg1.jpg);}`

What would be the java function to make the image scale to 100% width of the div bg1, bg2, etc. and have the overlay pattern enabled too.

Thanks for any help.

Regs Fab

Comment: I gave up Vegas plugin. I use MaxImage instead as it allows selecting an element here's an example http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/#FillElement hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

A quote from Jay Salvat (vegas.js developer) from January 2014 -

> Hello.
>
> Vegas manages full-screen backgrounds only. Not on a specific element.
>
> Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

Actually vegas plugin is meant for body backgrounds. It should work for `$(".bg1")` or any other element but its not working.

Explanation form jay salvat :

> Original $.vegas doesn't work anymore. $.vegas must apply the plugin on the body by default while $('tag').vegas must apply it to the specific tag.
>   Also, If I apply vegas to several tags, only the last one works. Multi-instance should be possible.
>   It would be great if you could find time to fix those issue !

Here is the link from jay salvat : [Jay Salvat's git comment](https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas/pull/23)

Hope it will solve your doubt to use for `<div>`